# Testing API call in Vue with Moxios

Tags: vue.js, karma-jasmine, vue-component, moxios

I am having trouble figuring out how to test an API call that happens in the "mounted" lifecycle hook.

I have a single file component that is responsible for displaying some information about an "Owner".

This works exactly how I want / expect in the browser.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Owner Information</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Social Security Number</th>
        <th>Ownership Percentage</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr :data-owner-id="owner.id" v-for="owner in owners">
          <td>{{ owner.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ owner.address }}</td>
          <td>{{ owner.censored_ssn }}</td>
          <td>{{ owner.ownership_percentage }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        principal_id: '',
        owners: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      const el = document.querySelector('#owner-information');
      this.principal_id = el.dataset.principal;

      var self = this;
      axios.get(`/principals/${this.principal_id}.json`).then(response => {
        response.data.owners.map((owner) => {
          owner.score = '';
          owner.link = '';
          owner.last_pull_date = '';
          self.owners.push(owner);
        });
      });
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

For testing, I am using Karma, Jasmine, and Avoriaz.

Here is a failing test:

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import OwnerInformation from '../../app/javascript/packs/OwnerInformation.vue'

describe('OwnerInformation', () => {
  let component

  beforeAll(() => {
    const element = document.createElement('div')
    element.setAttribute('id', 'owner-information')
    element.setAttribute('data-principal', '84033')
    document.body.appendChild(element)

    component = mount(OwnerInformation)
    component.vm.$mount('#owner-information')
  })

  it('retrieves owner information from the API', () => {
    expect(component.data().owners.length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

The above expects 1, but gets 0.

So now I figure that I need to stub/mock out my API request in some manner.  A quick Google search leads me to moxios.  So I install it with Yarn and eventually come up with this.  I am not 100% sure where to put moxios.stubRequest, but have tried putting it in beforeAll(), beforeEach(), and inside the "it".

```

```
import moxios from moxios
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import OwnerInformation from '../../app/javascript/packs/OwnerInformation.vue'

describe('OwnerInformation', () => {
  let component

  beforeAll(() => {
    const element = document.createElement('div')
    element.setAttribute('id', 'owner-information')
    element.setAttribute('data-principal', '12345')
    document.body.appendChild(element)

    component = mount(OwnerInformation)
    component.vm.$mount('#owner-information')
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall()
  })

  it('retrieves owner information from the API', () => {
    moxios.stubRequest('/principals/12345', {
      status: 200,
      response: {
        id: 1, owners: [
          { name: 'Test Owner', address: '123 Test St.', ssn: '123-12-1234', ownership_percentage: 100 
          }
        ]
      }
    })
    expect(component.data().owners.length).toBe(1)
  })
```

It appears that the request is not actually be stubbed out.  To troubleshoot, I put a console.log statement just before the axios.get() call (which logs out successfully) and I also put a console.log to log out the response, but this one never shows up which makes me think that the axios request is not working and is not getting "intercepted" by moxios.

```
...
      console.log('CALLING API...')
      axios.get(`/principals/${this.principal_id}.json`).then(response => {
        console.log('***********************')
...
```

When I run the test I do see a 404, but am unsure why:

`01 08 2017 12:49:43.483:WARN [web-server]: 404: /principals/12345.json`

To me, it makes most sense to stub out the request at the top of `beforeAll()`, but this does not work either.

How can I arrange this so that moxios stubs out the API request and it returns so that my test passes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `moxios.wait()` to wait for the moxios request to complete:

```js
/*** note the "done" argument -- you must call this method within wait()! ***/
it('retrieves owner information from the API', (done) => {
  moxios.stubRequest('/principals/12345', {
    status: 200,
    response: {
      id: 1, owners: [{ name: 'Test', address: '123 Test St.' }]
    }
  })
  moxios.wait(function() {
    expect(component.data().owners.length).toBe(1)
    done()
  })
})
```